# How to model complex schema without much repetition using JsonSchema?

Tags: json, schema, data-modeling, jsonschema

I am trying to model documents (such as passport) and their attributes (first name, birth date, etc) and describe them using `json schema`.

I want to define many types of documents in runtime, every document as a separate schema. 
Some attributes may be referenced from multiple documents, such as `firstName` in passport and in driver's license, so it is 
probably wise to create a separate attribute definition schema for this.

Lets say, I have a passport, its model looks like following:

```
{
  "owner":  "<string>",
  "type" :  "<string>",
  "salt" :  <number>,
  "attributes": {
    "number"     : {"value": "<string>",     "salt": <number>}
    "lastName"   : {"value": "<string>",     "salt": <number>},
    "firstName"  : {"value": "<string>",     "salt": <number>},
    "birthDate"  : {"value": "<date>",       "salt": <number>},
    "nationality": {"value": "<string>",     "salt": <number>},
  }
}
```

Every attribute has "value" and "salt", but "value" is different for every key (attribute name).
My question is, how will schema for this type of JSON document look?

**UPD**: every attribute has `value` and `salt`. Salt is exactly equal for all attributes, but `value` is different. If I manually specify that every attribute has `salt` and `value`, then I will end up with huge schema duplication. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Have you looked at the `$ref` keyword found in JSON Schema core?

Comment: @Relequestual sure. It can be used to reference "salt", for example. But how do I reference attribute schema? So that I don't repeat "value"+"salt" properties for every attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of things you can do to reduce the duplication in your schema. One way is to use the `definitions` keyword. Another option is to use `patternProperties` to validate common constraints across multiple properties.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "owner": { "type": "string" },
    "type": { "type": "string" },
    "salt": { "$ref": "#/definitions/salt" },
    "attributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "salt": { "$ref": "#/definitions/salt" }
          },
          "required": ["value", "salt"]
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "number": { "$ref": "#/definitions/string-value" },
        "lastName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/string-value" },
        "firstName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/string-value" },
        "birthDate": { "$ref": "#/definitions/date-value" },
        "nationality": { "$ref": "#/definitions/string-value" }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "salt": { "const": 1234 },
    "string-value": {
      "properties": {
        "value": { "type": "string" }
      }
    },
    "date-value": {
      "properties": {
        "value": { "type": "string", "format": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With draft-7 of JSON Schema (current at time of writing), assuming you'll want to be using references to another file which contains your property definitions, you may want to do something like the following.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "number": {
      "properties": {
        "value": {...}, # Whatever you define as your schema for number/value.
        "salt": {
          "$ref": "externalRef/definitions/salt"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not know that I can write "value: {}" property. It looks like it is something that I want. I will check and accept your answer, it so. Thank you!

Comment: I was omitting the schema you may set for it. Unless you specify `"additionalProperties": false`, you can have an values in your JSON object without restriction. In that schema, `"value": {},` has no impact.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to define pair "value"/"salt" for each of my attributes. Is there a way to reduce code duplication?

Comment: You said the value schema was different for each attribute though... Are you saying that there are a set number of value schemas which attributes might share? For example, first name and last name would share the same value schema?

Comment: Every attribute (firstName, lastName) contains "value" and "salt". "Salt" is the same everywhere, but "value" is different for every attribute. Sorry for unclear explanation.

Comment: Based on your updated question, what do you want the schema to validate? Just that each attribute object has the keys of "value" and "salt", or the specific format of the value and salt?

Comment: the value of the "value" field (its type), is different (it depends on the attribute):

`"firstName": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {<different for firstName, birthDate, etc>},
    "salt": {"$ref": "#/definitions/salt"}
  }
}`


I can specify all attributes in this way, but it introduces code duplication, so that I need to specify `value` and `salt` for all attributes.

Comment: I think we should move this to a discussion, but I'm unable to chat about this further till tomorrow. Feel free to do so here or join the JSON Schema slack and find me.